# How can I get In-App billing item price in onCreate method

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I'm using inappbilling in my project. Im getting item price with

```
String price = inventory.getSkuDetails(CARD25).getPrice();
```

How can I get this item's price in onCreate method?

Comment: What problem are you getting if putting this statement in onCreate ? Any parameters are coming as null ?

Comment: inventory is null in Oncreate, it is filling in QueryInventoryFinishedListener callback. @Stallion